# MongoDB query all documents contains ids that does not exist anymore in the collection

Tags: database, mongodb, list, mongodb-query, document

I ran into an issue that I haven't found a solution to yet.
I have a collection with dozens of documents that every one of the documents contains a list (let's use the name 'list' as a key for that list) with ids of other documents(they are connected in some way).

some of the documents in the collection were deleted and I try to find **all the documents that contain the ids of documents that do not exist anymore in the collection.**

example:

[image]

[image]

As to the example above: I want to get the document with the id : 5e3266e9bd724a000107a902 because it contains a list with the id 5e32a7f7bd724a00012c1104 that does not exist anymore.

Comment: Welcome!   What have you tried so far that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works exploiting `$lookup` on the *same* collection (think "self-JOIN"):

```js
var r = [
    {_id: 0, aa: [ 10, 11, 12 ] }
    ,{_id: 1, aa: [ 10, 11, 12 ] }
    ,{_id: 2, aa: [ 20, 21, 22 ] }  // 21 is on watch list...
    ,{_id: 3, aa: [ 21, 20, 12 ] }  // this one too and 21 is in different position
    ,{_id: 4, aa: [ 10, 22, 12 ] }  
    ,{_id: 5, aa: [ 10, 22, 23 ] }  // this one too...
    ,{_id: 6, aa: [ 10, 22, 21, 23 ] }  // this one has BOTH 21 and 23

    ,{_id: 10, X:10}
    ,{_id: 11, X:11}
    ,{_id: 12, X:12}
    ,{_id: 20, X:20}
    ,{_id: 21, X:21}
    ,{_id: 22, X:22}
    ,{_id: 23, X:23}
];

db.foo.insert(r);

// Here is the whole thing:                                                                    
db.foo.aggregate([ ]);

// Delete _id 21 and 23:                                                                            
db.foo.remove({_id: 21});
db.foo.remove({_id: 23});

// Double check:                                                                               
c = db.foo.aggregate([ ]);
                                                                                 

// Where does id 21 and/or 23 NOT exist anymore?  Note we don't ask for 21 or 23.
// We just know we expect a query to return docs that indicate 21 and/or 23
// are no longer there:                                                       
c = db.foo.aggregate([
    // NOTE!  By using localField:'aa', we are asking for EACH element in the
    // array to be used as a value to match to _id (in the same collection):
    {$lookup: {from: 'foo', localField: 'aa', foreignField: '_id', as: 'X'}},

    // Exploit "make a list of scalars from array of objects" notation by taking
    // input array $X and taking the _id field out:
    {$project: {X: {$setDifference: ["$aa", "$X._id"] }} },

    // Keep those that match -- and protect against against empty sets
    // with $ifNull to turn a null into an array of len 0:
    {$match: {$expr: {$gt:[{$size: {$ifNull:['$X',[]]}}, 0]}} }
]);

{ "_id" : 2, "X" : [ 21 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "X" : [ 21 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "X" : [ 23 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "X" : [ 21, 23 ] }
```

Comment: Great answer!  Is it necessary to guard against empty sets?  Won't `"$setDifference"` always return at least `[]` which has `"$size"` 0?  I tried it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wi5g_-GqKUr "Click me!").

Comment: @rickhg12hs  No; if `aa` is unset in a doc, then it evals to `null` in `$setDifference:[$aa, anything]` and will return null.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks!